# How to get values more than certain key in TreeMap

Tags: java, collections, treemap

I have a TreeMap with key , value pair as SessionIdNode

```
private class SessionNode 
{
    String sessionid;
    Timestamp time;


    private SessionNode (String sessionid, long  d)
    {
        this.time = new Timestamp(d);
        this.sessionid = sessionid;
    }


    public int hashCode()
    {
        return sessionid.hashCode();

    }

    public boolean equals(SessionNode node)
    {
        return this.sessionid.equals(node.sessionid);
    }


}
```

This class, is used internally in a TreeMap as below:

```
private final Comparator< SessionNode> sessionNodeComparator = new Comparator<SessionNode>() {
        @Override public int compare(SessionNode s1, SessionNode s2) 
        {
            return ((SessionNode)s1).time.compareTo(s2.time);   
        }           
    };

private Map <SessionNode , SessionNode> map = new TreeMap <SessionNode , SessionNode>( sessionNodeComparator);
```

Now, my question is , it sorts the SessionNodes on the basis of custom comparator, which is essentially according to time.

Now say given a time t1, I need to remove all the  keys in the treemap which have SessionNode timestamp value > t1.

How do I accomplish this??
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
map.tailMap(new SessionNode(null, t1), false).clear();
```

Comment: Since the hashcode is found from the sessionid , which is taken as null  , we cannot locate a sessionNode with null key, with that timestamp, so the tailmap we get out of this is the entire map again, After which we clear the entire map. So the elements now are 0. i need to clear after that timestamp t1. The elements previously should be retained. Thank you for your guidance. Or Do i need some other data structure for this purpose?